# What is the difference between assigning 1 arraylist to other vs adding 1 araylist to other empty araylist to make both of them contain same objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So what I basically mean is what are the difference between the following ?

```
List<String> phonesContainerOne = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> phonesContainerTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

phonesContainerOne.add("Nexus 4");
phonesContainerOne.add("Nexus 5");
```

now suppose I want to add both these phones to the phone container second.In java I can do that in the following ways

```
1.phonesContainerTwo.addAll(phonesContainerOne);

2.phonesContainerTwo = phonesContainerOne;
```

What exactly are the difference between the two ways (1 and 2) in my case ?(ps. i know that addAll is used to add objects of one Collection type to another at once.So besides this what are teh other difference between these ways?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are adding one list to other, while keeping both lists.
Here, phoneContainerTwo has been appended with the phoneContainerOne list.

In second case, your original reference to phoneContainerTwo is changed to phoneContainerOne, ie both now point to same data/memory.Moreover, you'll never be able to access the data earlier pointed by phoneContainerTwo.

Suppose Initially you have

```
PhoneContainerOne:     PhoneContainerTwo:
data 1               data 3
data 2               data 4
```

If case 1 is used,

```
PhoneContainerOne:     PhoneContainerTwo:
data 1               data 3
data 2               data 4
                     data 1
                     data 2
```

If case 2 is used,

```
PhoneContainerOne:
PhoneContainerTwo:     
data 1               
data 2
```

Answer (score 7):

When you do `addAll`, you get two separate lists, which can each be modified separately.  That is,

```
(phonesContainerOne) ⟶ [ Nexus4, Nexus5 ]

(phonesContainerTwo) ⟶ []
```

becomes

```
(phonesContainerOne) ⟶ [ Nexus4, Nexus5 ]

(phonesContainerTwo) ⟶ [ Nexus4, Nexus5 ]
```

However, if you just write `phonesContainerTwo = phonesContainerOne` then you end up with just a single list, but two variables referring to it.

```
(phonesContainerOne) ⟶ [ Nexus4, Nexus5 ] ⟵ (phonesContainerTwo)
```

Comment: what if you do something like containerOne.get(0).setName(Nexus44) then when I do containerTwo.get(0).getName will I get Nexus4 or Nexus44 ?

Comment: @KorayTugay - your example assumes these are not Strings, but some other kind of object - something that has a "name" property.  In that case, you'll get "Nexus44", because two references to the same object appear in the lists (one reference in each list), and you've changed the name of that one object that both references refer to.

Comment: I think this is very important in this situation.

Comment: But "this situation" is that the objects in the list are Strings.  And Strings are immutable.  So your question is ... well, a completely different question.

Answer (score 3):

Case no. 2 is only assigning `phonesContainerOne` to `phonesContainerTwo`. I.e, They are now pointing to the same object.

If you edit `phonesContainerTwo` content, `phonesContainerOne` will be also changed.

Comment: I think this is same for case 1.